# How to change the name of uploaded application

Tags: android

I have launched an android application in to the google play store and it's currently live. How ever, the app has no name. In the store itself, it has a name, but once you downloaded it, it's gone. Like the icon shows next to all your other apps, but there is no name under the small icon.

Does anyone know where I can add this? I saw something about the android:label in my AndroidManifest, but I get errors when I change that. It's currently `android:label="@string/app_name"`

This is my entire AndroidManifest.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.informatie.rodekruis"
    android:versionCode="2"
    android:versionName="1.1" >

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="8"
        android:targetSdkVersion="21" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme"
        android:icon="@mipmap/app_logo" >
        <activity
            android:name="com.example.rodekruis.MainActivity"
             android:label="@string/title_activity_main" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name="com.example.rodekruis.BezoekActivity"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_bezoek" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />

                <category android:name="com.example.rodekruis.BEZOEKACTIVITY" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name="com.example.rodekruis.AfspraakActivity"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_afspraak" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />

                <category android:name="com.example.rodekruis.AFSPRAAKACTIVITY" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name="com.example.rodekruis.ContactActivity"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_contact" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />

                <category android:name="com.example.rodekruis.CONTACTACTIVITY" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name="com.example.rodekruis.MeningActivity"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_mening" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />

                <category android:name="com.example.rodekruis.MENINGACTIVITY" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name="com.example.rodekruis.RouteActivity"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_route" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />

                <category android:name="com.example.rodekruis.ROUTEACTIVITY" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name="com.example.rodekruis.SpecialistenActivity"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_specialisten" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />

                <category android:name="com.example.rodekruis.SPECIALISTENACTIVITY" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name="com.example.rodekruis.BWCActivity"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_bwc" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />

                <category android:name="com.example.rodekruis.BWCACTIVITY" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name="com.example.rodekruis.AgendaActivity"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_agenda" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />

                <category android:name="com.example.rodekruis.AGENDAACTIVITY" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name="com.example.rodekruis.InfoActivity"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_informatie" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />

                <category android:name="com.example.rodekruis.INFOACTIVITY" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name="com.example.rodekruis.VriendActivity"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_vriend" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />

                <category android:name="com.example.rodekruis.VRIENDACTIVITY" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name="com.example.rodekruis.FoldersActivity"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_folders" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />

                <category android:name="com.example.rodekruis.FOLDERSACTIVITY" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name="com.example.rodekruis.NieuwsActivity"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_nieuws">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />

                <category android:name="com.example.rodekruis.NIEUWSACTIVITY" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

Comment: Go into you string resources. Located in src/main/res/values. Search for strings.xml. search the tag app_name and change the value. If you support multiple languages, then your values folder will have a postfix like values-ar (like arabic) and change the values within their strings.xml, too.

Comment: I already named it there. That name doesn't show up though

Comment: Which name did you use for the activity label title_activity_main ?

Comment: Nothing, i have no name there

Comment: remove the label from the activity

Answer (score 0):

Instead of your label in the `application` tag, Android is using your label of the `activity`, that has

```
<intent-filter>
 <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
 <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
</intent-filter>
```

in it. Android tries to be the most specific. And because, as you said, your value for the string resource

```
@string/title_activity_main
```

is empty (so an empty string basically, which is not an empty value) you don't see any label below your icon. You can check that against, if you open the application manager in the settings and search for your application. It should be named after your `app_name` resource.

You can now either change the value for your activity label, or instead (and I assume that is what you want to do), remove the label between `<activity ... />`.